# Difference between usb_alloc_coherent and kzalloc/kmalloc

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, device-driver

What is the fundamental difference between using `usb_alloc_coherent` and `kzalloc/kmalloc` in context of `USB` driver. Both does the same, allocate a memory area for `URB` buffer. But what is the difference of them. Is there any benefit of using `usb_alloc_coherent` instead of `kzalloc/kmalloc`?

Answer (score 1):

Drivers are device (endpoint) centric but memory allocation must consult capabilities of the USB controller.  This is because it is the controller which performs the DMA from memory onto the USB bus.  So `usb_alloc_coherent` basically wraps the generic `dma_alloc_coherent` but calls it for the controller, not the endpoint.  Using DMA-API instead of just `kmalloc` ensures that no bounce-buffers will be required.

This saves device driver writes from code ugliness (breaking abstractions) and handling of some corner cases.  `usb_alloc_coherent` also uses a memory poll to speed things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says:

> usb_alloc_coherent - allocate dma-consistent buffer for URB_NO_xxx_DMA_MAP
>
> These buffers are used with URB_NO_xxx_DMA_MAP set in `urb->transfer_flags`
>   to avoid behaviors like using "DMA bounce buffers", or thrashing IOMMU
>   hardware during URB completion/resubmit.